# Get MIN value for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, min

Im trying to get the min time for each call. Each call can have sevealr parts to it all logged on the same call id. What I want to do is fine the min time for each call id but im getting duplicate values when I query it one way or if I query it another way I just get the min value.

I want to end up with being able to count all the calls by hour

this is the query I have been playing with to try and get the unique call id and time but this returns duplicates currently

eg:

Callid 1 = 2014-07-04 16:37:22.043

callid 2 = 2014-07-04 16:37:23.370

what I want is just the values from called 1

```
select t.callid, (select min(timein) from loggeddata t2 where t2.callid = t.callid and t2.timein > t.timein
                    ) as 'mintime'
      from loggeddata t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for that, just use `GROUP BY` to define the grouping expression and add the aggregation as a column:

```
select t.callid, 
       min(timein) as 'mintime' 
from loggeddata 
GROUP BY callid
```

Comment: Thanks such a simple answer in the end too this was part of a bigger query and the obvious answer just wasn't standing out for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
select callid,min(timein) from loggedata group by callid;
```

Comment: Sorry I marked the person who gave the answer first, you can only have one correct answer as marked so when with the one I used but yours did the same job.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
select t.callid, (select min(timein) from loggeddata t2 where t2.callid = t.callid and t2.timein > t.timein
                    ) as 'mintime'
      from loggeddata t

)

Select c.callid,c.mintime from (select
             row_number() over (partition by mintime order by callid desc) as seqnum
      from  CTE )c
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer, turning this into a cte was my next option to look at making the overall query more simple as its got allot more parts to it then just this bit, I don't have enough reputation to mark this answer though

Comment: No Problem..if it gives the solution what you want then it's like more than getting points :)